# DNS Server on AD logging queries even when disabled

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, logging

I have two Server 2012 R2 DCs running DNS.

The DNS server has Debug Logging turned off in the GUI, however I am getting daily 500MB `dns#TIMESTAMP#.log` files in `C:\Windows\System32\DNS\Logs\`

I ran the PowerShell **`get-dnsserverdiagnostics`**

```
SaveLogsToPersistentStorage          : True
Queries                              : False
Answers                              : False
Notifications                        : False
Update                               : False
QuestionTransactions                 : False
UnmatchedResponse                    : False
SendPackets                          : False
ReceivePackets                       : False
TcpPackets                           : False
UdpPackets                           : False
FullPackets                          : False
FilterIPAddressList                  :
EventLogLevel                        : 2
UseSystemEventLog                    : False
EnableLoggingToFile                  : True
EnableLogFileRollover                : True
LogFilePath                          : c:\windows\system32\dns\logs\dns.log
MaxMBFileSize                        : 500000000
WriteThrough                         : False
EnableLoggingForLocalLookupEvent     : True
EnableLoggingForPluginDllEvent       : True
EnableLoggingForRecursiveLookupEvent : True
EnableLoggingForRemoteServerEvent    : True
EnableLoggingForServerStartStopEvent : True
EnableLoggingForTombstoneEvent       : True
EnableLoggingForZoneDataWriteEvent   : True
EnableLoggingForZoneLoadingEvent     : True
```

The top section Queries - FullPackets appears to be the DNS Debug Logging section. Where would EnableLoggingtoFile and SaveLogs be available to disable in the GUI? The 500MB files a day clog up the hard drive as time goes on, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was discovered that the GUI DNS Debug Log properties controls the top section, Queries - FullPackets, but that if the bottom section was set to True, they would be logged, even if `SaveLogsToPersistentStorage`  was set to False.

This was confirmed by comparing the log data with and without the bottom section enabled. DNS Logs with the standard GUI DNS Debug Log properties data enabled look like:

```
8/17/2018 9:08:39 AM 1B70 PACKET  00000041E490A160 UDP Snd 8.8.4.4         524b   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (8)clients6(6)google(3)com(0)
8/17/2018 9:08:39 AM 1B70 PACKET  00000041E38B8170 UDP Snd 10.200.56.5     a3ae R Q [8081   DR  NOERROR] A      (8)clients6(6)google(3)com(0)
```

But the more detailed logs look like this:

```
8/15/2018 9:52:55 PM 1338 LOOKUP  Writing AAAA records for node #DC#.local. (000000D5CAC007C0)
                     to additional section of packet 000000D5CC19A130
8/15/2018 9:52:55 PM 1338 LOOKUP  Writing A records for node #DC#.local. (000000D5CAC004A0)
                     to additional section of packet 000000D5CC19A130
8/15/2018 9:52:55 PM 1338 LOOKUP  Writing AAAA records for node #DC#.local. (000000D5CAC004A0)
                     to additional section of packet 000000D5CC19A130
8/15/2018 9:52:55 PM 1338 LOOKUP  Writing A records for node #DC#.local. (000000D5CABFD330)
                     to additional section of packet 000000D5CC19A130
8/15/2018 9:52:55 PM 1338 LOOKUP  Writing AAAA records for node #DC#.local. (000000D5CABFD330)
                     to additional section of packet 000000D5CC19A130
8/15/2018 9:52:55 PM 1338 LOOKUP  Query name (1)1(1)0(1)0(3)127(7)in-addr(4)arpa(0)
                     zone          127.in-addr.arpa (type 1)
                     node          1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa. (000000D5CABF6B40)
                     closest node  1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa. (000000D5CABF6B40)
```

As such, I turned off the advanced logging options with Powershell via:

```
set-dnsserverdiagnostics 
-EnableLoggingForLocalLookupEvent False 
-EnableLoggingForPluginDllEvent False 
-EnableLoggingForRecursiveLookupEvent False 
-EnableLoggingForRemoteServerEvent False 
-EnableLoggingForServerStartStopEvent False 
-EnableLoggingForTombstoneEvent False 
-EnableLoggingForZoneDataWriteEvent False 
-EnableLoggingForZoneLoadingEvent False
```

Answer (score 0):

For DNS on Windows Server 2019, in addition to Greg's recommendations, I also had to set LogFilePath to $null. Before that the log file kept reappearing whenever I started the DNS service.

Set-DnsServerDiagnostics -LogFilePath $null